# How can I transfer data from one array to another in a separate view controller?

Tags: ios, arrays, nsmutablearray

I'm creating an iOS app that on the first screen shows a list of items held in an array titled itemsList

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *itemsList;
```

When tapping the + button to add an item, an array of preset items appear titled addNewItem

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *addNewItem;
```

When that cell is tapped, how can I transfer the data in the tapped cell to the itemsList array, completely removing it from the addNewItem array since they are in two different implementation files?

Answer (score 0):

First off, use ARC, so declare your properties as such:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *itemsList;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *addNewItem;
```

Then:

```
[self.itemsList addItemsFromArray:self.addNewItem];
[self.addNewItem removeAllObjects];
```

That should do it.

Comment: But they are in two different .m files. So how do I go about transferring between the files?

Answer (score 0):

```
// FirstViewController
// .h File
SecondViewController *sec;
NSMutableArray *arrayWhichYouPass;
// .m File
arrayWhichYouPass = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arrayWhichYouPass addObject:@"Jayesh"];
[arrayWhichYouPass addObject:@"Jatin"];
[arrayWhichYouPass addObject:@"Jay"];
[arrayWhichYouPass addObject:@"Vishal"];
[arrayWhichYouPass addObject:@"Amit"];

- (IBAction) buttonClicked : (id) sender
{
sec = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"SecondViewController"]...];
sec.arrGetData = arrayWhichYouPass;
}

// SecondViewController
// .h File
// Give Property to array which get the array data from FirstViewController

@property (nonautomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrGetData;

// .m File
@sysnthesize arrGetData;

NSLog(@"%@",arrGetData);
```